# React manage form input tied to dynamic state names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling an api, then based on the results am dynamically creating a number of state variables.  I also am using a dynamically referenced value for the input value.  I don't think the values are synching up... the input value for the example provided is '0'.  Am I wiring this up correctly?

```
initializeInputs() {
var outerState = this;
this.state.data.forEach(function(element) {
  //console.log(element);
  var stateTitle = "title" + element.id;
  var stateLocation = "location" + element.id;
  var stateDescription = "description" + element.id;
  var stateStartDate = "startdate" + element.id;
  var stateEndDate = "enddate" + element.id;
  outerState.setState({ [stateTitle]: element.title });
  outerState.setState({ [stateLocation]: element.location });
  outerState.setState({ [stateDescription]: element.description 
});
  outerState.setState({ [stateStartDate]: element.startdate });
  outerState.setState({ [stateEndDate]: element.enddate });
});
}

{data.length <= 0
? 'NO DB ENTRIES YET'
: data.map((dat) => (
    <input className={"event-title-input event-input event-main-input input"+dat.id} name={"title"+dat.id} value={this.state.title+dat.id} onChange={this.handleChange} style={{ display: 'none' }} />)
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the properties in state correctly by using bracket notation for dynamic key names, but not accessing them the same way. Try:

```
value={this.state[title + dat.id]}
```

Comment: bracket notation is [computed property names](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames)

Comment: setState is asynchronous, so if you have a lot of data it may take a while to update everything.  I'd try aggregating all of your setState calls into one singular call, you can update multiple values using a single object.